# Linux Mint Eclipse GLFW 3 Setup problems

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, glfw

I have, in my opinion, installed and configured GLFW 3 correctly,
my compiler tells me otherwise.

glfw3.h and glfw3native.h are in urs/local/include/GLFW/.

libglfw3.a is in urs/local/lib/.

In Eclipse, i configured in Project Propreties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C Linker->Libraries the following values : GL, GLU, m, rt, pthread, m, glfw3, X11, Xxf86vm, Xrandr and Xi.

In my project, in Test.c i have the following test code :

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : Test.c
 Author      : 
 Version     :
 Copyright   : Your copyright notice
 Description : Hello World in C, Ansi-style
 ============================================================================
*/
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */

     if (!glfwInit())
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So in my opinion and what i have read one the internet, it seems an alright setup.
When i compile it it gives this :

```
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(window.c.o): In function `glfwCreateWindow':
window.c:(.text+0x724): undefined reference to `glClear'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): In function `getFBConfigAttrib':
glx_context.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `glXGetFBConfigAttrib'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): In function `chooseFBConfig':
glx_context.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `glXGetClientString'
glx_context.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `glXGetFBConfigs'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): In function `createLegacyContext':
glx_context.c:(.text+0x41f): undefined reference to `glXCreateNewContext'
```

Reading this i came to the conclusion that it didn't find OpenGL, but i already made OpenGL projects before and it works, so why can GLFW find it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tickering around and praying for this problem to go away for a couple hours, and days. I have found the solution... and i don't fully understand why linking is so hard.

What i did is just try different Linker Libraries option, 
This order is the one that worked for me :

-lglfw3 -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -Xxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -lm

Hope this helps others.